# How to add an unreachable git commit to stash by its hash

Tags: git, git-stash

I have the hashes of a large number of unreachable commits (silly me trying to `clear` the console while I had `git stash` typed in)

I've got a bunch of these hashes from a bit of messing around with git fsck

Is there any easy way to `xargs` these hashes back into the git stash?

Comment: Your title says "unreadable" but your description says "unreachable", which is it?

Comment: unreachable. my bad. still not typing straight >.>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fast answer:

```
 git fsck | grep commit | cut -d' ' -f3 |
   while read hash; do git rev-parse --verify --quiet $hash^2 && echo $hash; done |
   xargs git log --grep WIP --pretty=oneline |
   while read hash wip on branch commit junk; do
    git checkout $hash;  git reset --soft $commit;  git stash; done
```

Note that this will separate the index and working tree parts of the stash into different stashes.  Can you give an example of the output you saved?  There are multiple parts to a stash and you may not have the SHA for all of the parts.

Edited to include your sample stash discovery script to reproduce the stash from the right relative base.

Comment: I've got it out to a big list of `HASH WIP on master: commit message` using `git fsck | grep commit | cut -d' ' -f3 | while read hash; do git rev-parse --verify --quiet $hash^2 && echo $hash; done | xargs git log --grep WIP --pretty=oneline`

Comment: which then gets piped to `awk '{print $1}'` for just the hashes -- I know that I am under the assumption that all stashed commits have 'WIP' in the commit message

Comment: @arcyqwerty: Then my answer will reconnect all bits and put them in the stash, though of course as I said if you have multiple lines of output with the same comment (meaning both the index and working directory were differently stashed) then they will form two stashes.  Let me know if this happens to you or if you care.  I could try investigating making a more sophisticated reconnect

Comment: As far as I know, they were stashes simply using the `git stash` command. nothing too fancy

Comment: @arcyqwerty: The question isn't what command you ran, but rather the state of the repo when you ran the command.  If you had `git add`ed some files and not added some others, you would actually have two "commits" as part of the stash.  My quick fix would turn the index part and the working directory part into two different stashes.

Comment: clean repo, everything had just been stashed right before stash was cleared
no untracked files, staged files, etc

Comment: @acryqwerty: Updated to use your script and set up the correct base for the stash.

Comment: Thanks! I think I got them all back!